# Convert tokens to corpus

Tags: r

I have a variable name df which is a character vector.

As a preprocessing step I would like to remove stopwords and my own list of stopwords. After that I would like to create a corpus from the previous example and a dfm.

I use the following command lines:

```
library(quanteda)
datastopwords_removed <- tokens_remove(tokens(df2, remove_punct = TRUE), c(stopwords("english"), mystopwords$phrases))
mycorpus <- corpus(datastopwords_remove)
myDfm <- dfm(datastopwords_remove, ngrams = c(1,5))
```

But in corpus I receive this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("corpus") : 
  no applicable method for 'corpus' applied to an object of class "tokens"
```

How can I fix it? Also if I have in mystopword list phrases with more than one token should I make any special handling because it works and I didn't received an error so I suppose it removes them.

Comment: `?corpus` tells you what the function exects as first argument;  `sapply(datastopwords_remove, paste, collapse=" ")` would for example give you a character vector, which it could process. The removal function removes the strings you specify in connection with the valuetype they represent: `abcd_efc` won't remove `abcd`, as you prly can inspect yourself easily... `tokens_remove(tokens(c("abcd_efg", "hij")), c("abcd", "abcd_efgh"))`...

Comment: @lukeA thank you ok I can understand that corpus can't  take the format. However I am confused how can I transform my code properly?

Comment: Please use reproducible examples, e.g. built-in data objects, or provide the objects in your post (for `d2` for instance). There is a reference to "the previous example" but this is unclear. You should also clearly specify what output format you want and why.

Comment: That's a different problem and not related to **quanteda**.

Comment: @KenBenoit thank you I found what was wrong. From the example code I found I tried to use with quanteda the initial code had this `length(corpus)` and in order to use it with quanteda I should use this `length(corpus$documents$texts)`

Comment: Suggest you use `ndoc(corpus)` rather than accessing the object internals, since these are subject to change.

Comment: @KenBenoit thank you very much. Any suggestion for different call also for this corpus$documents$texts[[i]]?

Comment: `texts(corpus)[i]`